# Forms Authenticated web application with Basic Auth on a specific folder/path

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, basic-authentication

I have a Forms Authenticated web application but I need Basic Authentication on a couple of services which are all located at a specific path (ie. "~/Services/").

I originally tried to add a  tag in the web.config with a seperate custom MembershipProvider for the path like so:

```
  <location path="Services">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None" />
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <membership defaultProvider="ServicesMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="Company.WebProject.DeviceMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </membership>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="BasicAuthentication" type="Company.WebProject.BasicAuthenticationModule" />
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But this was throwing errors:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition= 'MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can  be  caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an  application in IIS.

So I realised that I wasn't allowed to use the authentication element in a location element.

After reading [this](http://www.arcomit.co.uk/support/kb.aspx?kbid=000041) article, I then tried hooking into the FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate method in the Global.asax. As I need to use Basic Authentication, I tried returning a 401 to prompt the browser for basic auth credentials. Unfortunately, it seems this was causing a redirect to the Forms Authentication log on page (ie. loginUrl).

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    string path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(e.Context.Request.Path);
    if (path.Contains("/Services/"))
    {
        e.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        e.Context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", "CompanyRealm"));
        e.Context.Response.End();                
    }
}
```

So now I have run out of ideas as to how to implement Basic Auth on a folder in a Forms Authenticated web application.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `Forms Authentication` with `Windows Authentication` in ASP.NET. You will need to create either a separate application for the two or you will need to implement `Forms Authentication` and `Roles` to properly do tiered access.

Comment: Thanks for the response although if you google it, you will find there are a few solutions on the web to mix Forms Authentication and Windows Authentication. Unfortunately for me, I need Forms Auth and Basic Auth (not Windows Auth). I am aware that I can create seperate applications but this is not my ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the day, but I've posted some code here:
[Combining Forms Authentication and Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830243/asp-net-combining-forms-authentication-and-basic-authentication)

Basically you just need to replace

```
e.Context.Response.End();
```

with

```
e.Context.Response.Flush(); 
e.Context.Response.Close();
```

Closing the Response object seems to prevent ASP from overriding the redirect. See the above link for full code.