# Combining Forms Authentication and Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have some core ASP code that I want to expose both by secure web pages (using Forms Authentication) and via web services (using Basic Authentication).

The solution that I've come up with seems to work, but am I missing anything here?

First, the whole site runs under HTTPS.

Site is set to use Forms authentication in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Then I override the AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax, to trigger Basic Authentication on the web service pages:

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if requesting the web service - this is the only page
    //that should accept Basic Authentication
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    if (app.Context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/Service/MyService.asmx"))
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Web service requested by user " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Debug("Null user - use basic auth");

            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            bool authenticated = false;

            // look for authorization header
            string authHeader = ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
            {
                // extract credentials from header
                string[] credentials = extractCredentials(authHeader);

                // because i'm still using the Forms provider, this should
                // validate in the same way as a forms login
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(credentials[0], credentials[1]))
                {
                    // create principal - could also get roles for user
                    GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(credentials[0], "CustomBasic");
                    GenericPrincipal p = new GenericPrincipal(id, null);
                    ctx.User = p;

                    authenticated = true;
                }
            }

            // emit the authenticate header to trigger client authentication
            if (authenticated == false)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                ctx.Response.AddHeader(
                    "WWW-Authenticate",
                    "Basic realm=\"localhost\"");
                ctx.Response.Flush();
                ctx.Response.Close();

                return;
            }
        }
    }            
}

private string[] extractCredentials(string authHeader)
{
    // strip out the "basic"
    string encodedUserPass = authHeader.Substring(6).Trim();

    // that's the right encoding
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    string userPass = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUserPass));
    int separator = userPass.IndexOf(':');

    string[] credentials = new string[2];
    credentials[0] = userPass.Substring(0, separator);
    credentials[1] = userPass.Substring(separator + 1);

    return credentials;
}
```

Comment: Just use a `<location>` configuration with drilled-down security changes. This looks dangerous.

Comment: Can you elaborate? <location> doesnt allow you to select different providers for different locations (this is a limitation of asp.net).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of: `<location><system.web><authentication></authentication></system.web></location>`

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e(v=vs.71).aspx "Configures ASP.NET authentication support. This element can be declared only at the machine, site, or application level. Any attempt to declare it in a configuration file at the subdirectory or page level will result in a parser error message."

Answer (score 11):

.Net 4.5 has a new Response property: **SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect**. When set to true it prevents redirecting a 401 response to the login page of the website. You can use the following code snippet in your global.asax.cs to enable Basic Authentication for e.g. the /HealthCheck folder.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Authenticates the application request.
  /// Basic authentication is used for requests that start with "/HealthCheck".
  /// IIS Authentication settings for the HealthCheck folder:
  /// - Windows Authentication: disabled.
  /// - Basic Authentication: enabled.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
  /// <param name="e">A <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
  protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
     if (application.Context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/HealthCheck", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
        {
           var context = HttpContext.Current;
           context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I got a solution to work based on the OP's ideas and the pointers from Samuel Meacham.

In global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoesUrlNeedBasicAuth() && Request.IsSecureConnection) //force https before we try and use basic authentication
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _log.Debug("Web service requested by user " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Debug("Null user - use basic auth");

                HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

                bool authenticated = false;

                // look for authorization header
                string authHeader = ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
                {
                    // extract credentials from header
                    string[] credentials = extractCredentials(authHeader);

                    //Lookup credentials (we'll do this in config for now)
                    //check local config first
                    var localAuthSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("apiUsers") as ApiUsersSection;
                    authenticated = CheckAuthSectionForCredentials(credentials[0], credentials[1], localAuthSection);

                    if (!authenticated)
                    {
                        //check sub config
                        var webAuth = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("apiUsers") as ApiUsersSection;
                        authenticated = CheckAuthSectionForCredentials(credentials[0], credentials[1], webAuth);
                    }
                }

                // emit the authenticate header to trigger client authentication
                if (authenticated == false)
                {
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    ctx.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate","Basic realm=\"localhost\"");
                    ctx.Response.Flush();
                    ctx.Response.Close();

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detect if current request requires basic authentication instead of Forms Authentication.
    /// This is determined in the web.config files for folders or pages where forms authentication is denied.
    /// </summary>
    public bool DoesUrlNeedBasicAuth()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string path = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
        if (context.SkipAuthorization) return false;

        //if path is marked for basic auth, force it

        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWith(Request.ApplicationPath + "/integration", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) return true; //force basic

        //if no principal access was granted force basic auth
        //if (!UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(path, context.User, context.Request.RequestType)) return true;

        return false;
    }

    private string[] extractCredentials(string authHeader)
    {
        // strip out the "basic"
        string encodedUserPass = authHeader.Substring(6).Trim();

        // that's the right encoding
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        string userPass = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUserPass));
        int separator = userPass.IndexOf(':');

        string[] credentials = new string[2];
        credentials[0] = userPass.Substring(0, separator);
        credentials[1] = userPass.Substring(separator + 1);

        return credentials;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the given basic authentication details can be granted access. Assigns a GenericPrincipal to the context if true.
    /// </summary>
    private bool CheckAuthSectionForCredentials(string username, string password, ApiUsersSection section)
    {
        if (section == null) return false;
        foreach (ApiUserElement user in section.Users)
        {
            if (user.UserName == username && user.Password == password)
            {
                Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.Name, "Basic"), user.Roles.Split(','));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The credentials that are allowed access are stored in a custom section in the web.config but you can store these how you wish.

HTTPS is required in the code above but this restriction can be removed if you wish. 
**EDIT** But as correctly pointed out in the comments this probably isn't a good idea due to the username and password being encoded and visible in plain text. Of course, even with the HTTPS restriction here, you can't stop an external request from trying to use insecure HTTP and sharing their credentials with anyone watching the traffic.

A path on which to force basic authentication is hardcoded here for now but obviously could be put in config or some other source. In my case the 'integration' folder was set to allow anonymous users.

There's a line commented out here involving `CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` that will grant access to any page on the site using basic auth if a user is not logged in via Forms Authentication.

Using `Application_AuthenticateRequest` instead of `Application_AuthorizeRequest` ended up being important as `Application_AuthorizeRequest` would force basic auth but then redirect to the Forms Authentication login page anyway. I didn't succeed in making this work by playing with the location based permissions in web.config and never found the reason for this. Swapping to `Application_AuthenticateRequest` did the trick so I left it at that.

The result of this left me with a folder that could be accessed using basic auth over HTTPS inside an application that normally uses Form Authentication. Logged in users can access the folder anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: >>HTTPS is required in the code above but this restriction can be removed if you wish<<< This is a REALLY BAD idea :) Basic auth uses plain-text login/password details, so your passwords can be easily intercepted if you don't use HTTPS.

Comment: I agree, I never said it was a good idea :p I'll edit it to make that clearer though.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path I think. I'm not sure you should be doing the work in **authenticate** request, however. That's when the user is identified, not when permission to the resource is checked (that's later in **authorize** request).  First, in your web.config, use `<location>` to remove forms auth for resources where you want to use basic auth.

#### Web.config

```
<configuration>
    <!-- don't require forms auth for /public -->
    <location path="public">
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

#### Global.asax.cs or wherever (an IHttpModule, etc.)

Then, instead of hard coding specific handlers or trying to parse the url to see if you're in a specific folder, in `Application_AuthorizeRequest`, something like the following will make everything secure by default (forms auth 1st, basic auth if forms auth has been removed via `<location>` settings in web.config).

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks to see if the current request can skip authorization, either because context.SkipAuthorization is true,
/// or because UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal() returns true for the current request/user/url.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool DoesUrlRequireAuth()
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    string path = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
    return context.SkipAuthorization ||
        UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(
            path, context.User, context.Request.RequestType);
}

void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DoesUrlRequireAuth())
    {
        // request protected by forms auth
    }
    else
    {
        // do your http basic auth code here
    }
}
```

Untested (just typed inline here), but I've done a lot with custom membership providers, your requirements are totally doable.

Hope some of this is helpful =)